# Do not show photo twice in Prettyphoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, prettyphoto

i have a tricky problem I'm not able to solve. I'm using `jquery.prettyphoto.js` to display a set of images in a "lightbox".

The first photo in that set is the "AvatarPhoto" and it's rendered twice on the page. First on top, standing alone and also in a slider with all the other photos. Both are linking to the same picture in the same gallery.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/wtZLY/

okay I solved that based on halfer´s answer, simply gave the first link of "allFotos" an id :

```
    $('#profilePicture').click(function() {
    $('#foto_0').click();
    });
```

but I wonder if I can´t use the prettyphoto API

```
$.prettyPhoto.open()
```

but looks like I there is no possibility to simply open the `prettyPhoto[gallery1]` down on the page. I would have to pass all images and titles as an Array and in my case this would be heavy repeating myself.

Comment: Can you publish what you have on a test site, such as JSFiddle or similar? I think the problem is too specific to determine the cause from just a description.

Comment: yeaah i just found the time to fiddlet it out. http://jsfiddle.net/wtZLY/

Comment: In which place do you want it shown? at the top or in the gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector works on this attribute:

```
data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"
```

If it is not your intention to add the first picture to the gallery, remove the `data-rel` attribute from that image, and it will work.

Personally, I'd use standard tags/ids/classes for this. In your JS you could alternatively use this:

```
$("#allpictures a").prettyPhoto();
```

That will select all links that are a descendent of the `allpictures` element.

Addendum: if you want to open the gallery using your profile picture, then I suggest you use the above for the gallery items, but have a special click handler for the profile. Set up an `id` for each image, such that the profile picture can be used to determine the gallery copy. For example you could use `profile_123` and `gallery_123`.

This will permit you to add a click handler on the profile image, derive the `id` of the gallery copy, and to raise the click event on that element.

Comment: ah no i used this selector because the "prettyphoto-initial was "rel" and rel is not valid attribute for img-tag, data-rel is. And i would love to open the same gallery by both: clicking on profilPicture and all Pictures but in the lightbox show it not twice.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain your first sentence a bit more? Do your images all _have_ to use this attribute?

Comment: yeah i will try this, you´ll get feedback

Comment: yeah, raising click event of the first anchor of AllPhotos did it and was very very simple,  thank you for you time :D